# Conditional visibility for one criteria

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report that groups by a task name and has a column called StartDate. For some of these tasks, I need to all the rows to be displayed even if a StartDate is null. However, on one task, I need to hide the rows if the StartDate is null.

Essentially I need a conditional clause that states if the task name is equal to abc and the StartDate is null, hide the row. I cannot figure out how to implement this into a visibility expression without it completely removing all the other rows because they don't match the criteria. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: in that case just add that to where clause to exclude `(Task <> 'abc' and StartDate is null)`

Comment: That will completely remove all instance of when a task equals 'abc'. If I add something like: `WHERE TaskName = 'abc' and StarDate IS NOT NULL`, all the other tasks will not show. @SaUce

Comment: I'm still confused on what exactly you are asking.

Comment: The user can select what task they want to view from a drop down. I am grouping by the task name. The tasks have a Start Date column, and those columns can be null for some tasks. If the user selects the task 'abc', I need to hide the rows if the StartDate is null. I cannot add it to the WHERE clause because it will completely remove all the other tasks because that condition is not met. I need to add it to a visibility expression but I cannot figure out how to do such. @SaUce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **Row Visibility** to achieve this.

Say I have data:

[image]

And a simple table based on this:

[image]

If I want to display task `ABC` rows with NULL start dates only, and all other tasks for non NULL start dates only, we can set the **Row Visibility** -> **Hidden** expression as:

```
=IIf((Fields!TaskName.Value = "ABC" and Not IsNothing(Fields!StartDate.Value))
    or (Fields!TaskName.Value <> "ABC" and IsNothing(Fields!StartDate.Value))
  , true
  , false)
```

Looks OK with this:

[image]

**Edit after comment**

If you want to only consider `ABC` for hiding certain rows, just change the **Row Visibility** -> **Hidden** expression to always show all non ABC rows:

```
=IIf((Fields!TaskName.Value = "ABC" and IsNothing(Fields!StartDate.Value))
    or Fields!TaskName.Value <> "ABC"
  , false
  , true)
```

[image]

Comment: BIDS is tossing me the following error:

`... The Visibility.Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object ...)`

I think this is because you have specified an OR argument. Also, if the TaskName isn't ABC, I need it to show both results (if StartDate is null or not null), which is where I am having trouble.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I've added a slightly changed expression which shows some slightly different functionality. The error you are getting is due to the way you have written your particular expression - you can nest `and` and `or` statements as required. Most likely it's a case of a missing or extra parenthesis. I can confirm the expressions in the answer are OK - the screenshots in my answer are directly from a BIDS preview, with report items using those exact expressions.

Comment: Perfect, all is working as intended now. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this condition to your `Where` clause will filter out that task:

```
where TaskName <> "ABC" or StartDate is null
```